# xmpp presence showing up on one device only

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

Presence issue has been asked before however I am not able to find any solution to my problem. Here's what I have done:

I have added selected for auto-subscription:

```
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;
```

I am sending my presense with "availbale" keyword. Now when I run my application:

1. Run application on Device1
2. Run application on Device2

Device 1 shows that Device2 is online but Device2 doesn't show that Device1 is online.

I am getting presence like this on Device2:

```
<Warning>: Presence : <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="Device2@abc.com/652873306-tigase-13" to="Device2@abc.com"><show>chat</show><status>available</status></presence>

<Warning>: Presence : <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="Device1@abc.com/652873306-tigase-11" to="Device2@abc.com"><show>chat</show><status>available</status></presence>
```

However even after getting this presence my fetch view controller is not seeing any new content. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What "new content" it should see?

Comment: I did some more debugging and for some reason my user is gone from the "XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage" database model. By the time presence comes back and it searches for the user, there is nothing. Not sure why my roster is empty. If I send my presence with some delay, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue. I found out that this issue was linked to to XMPP framework itself.